# Magento 2 - Error on running update/cron.php

Tags: magento2, error, cron

I'm getting an error on running `update/cron.php`

I setup the cronjob according to the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_cron.html). But it gives the following error:

> PHP Warning:  require_once(update/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in update/app/bootstrap.php on line 13
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'update/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in update/app/bootstrap.php on line 13

I found that the path `update/vendor/autoload.php` is wrong. The autoload.php should be at `/vendor` instead. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I finally figure out the issue. I have to run `composer install` at `<magento_dir>/update/`.

Comment: That is correct. But surely this should be done automatically when doing a composer install for magento2? Is this a bug? Still happens in 2.1.3

Comment: what kind of precautions we need to take care?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259389/magento-2-2-3-cron-error  please advise

Comment: @Paul can u guide me how to fix this? ASAP

Answer (score -1):

According to an internal Magento issue, that error indicates cron is running out of memory. Try increasing your PHP `memory_limit` to at least `1G`; in fact, I believe we're going to start recommending `2G` but that's not confirmed.

After you do that, restart your web server.

And by the way, sometimes you have two `php.ini` files: one for the PHP CLI and one for the web server plug-in. Change them both. See [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html#instgde-prereq-timezone) to determine if you have one or two.

Comment: It is not a memory issue. The error said `update/vendor/autoload.php` does not exist

Comment: This is the error I see in the internal issue. The cause is attributed to running out of memory: 

`Warning: require_once(/magento2/update/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /magento2/update/app/bootstrap.php on line 13`

Comment: I have set `memory_limit = 2G` but still failed

Comment: If you have two `php.ini` files, you must set `memory_limit` in both. If you rule that out, and you know `autoload.php` exists, then I don't know, sorry.

Comment: I have double checked and the memory limit is set correctly. But the error still happens.