# Magento 2.1, Help figuring out Cron job error

Tags: magento-2.1, cron, crontab

So I'm testing my cron jobs, and found out I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/php70 -c /etc/opt/remi/php70/php.ini /home/user/public_html/update/cron.php >> /home/user/public_html/var/log/update.cron.log
```

> PHP Warning: 
>   require_once(/home/user/public_html/update/vendor/autoload.php): 
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/user/public_html/update/app/bootstrap.php on line 13 PHP Fatal
>   error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/user/public_html/update/vendor/autoload.php' 
>   (include_path='.:/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in  /home/user/public_html/update/app/bootstrap.php on line 13

I've looked at the bootstrap, which is attempting to load the `autoload.php`, which I have no idea what its supposed to do.

Comment: turns out I found the solution here:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127827/magento-2-error-on-running-update-cron-php

I needed to run composer install from the update folder. However, I'm not sure WHY that was needed in the first place.