# Magento 2.2.3 cron Errors how to solve?

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron

we are running website Magento 2.2.3 CE version. We are getting an error in cron.log please advise?

1. **cron.log**

> Warning: require_once(/srv/public_html/update/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /srv/public_html/update/app/bootstrap.php on line 15

2. **update.log**

   We did some R&D and found that vendor directory was missing in /srv/public_html/update/ then we have moved **vendor** directory to respected path now the above error gone but getting below error.

> Update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable
>   paths

3. **exception.log**

> [2019-01-29 06:40:06] main.CRITICAL: No callbacks found
>   {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): No callbacks found at
>   /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:278)"}
>   []

How to fix these error? Can any one help?
Thanks

Comment: make sure you have the right permission for vendor folder or check if `autoload.php` was in there.

Comment: yes it has correct permissions. but it is saying /srv/public_html/update/vendor/autoload.php) this path....

Comment: do you use ssh ?

Comment: yes @magefms  we r using ssh.

Comment: @magefms please see the permissions https://prnt.sc/md2mt3

Answer (score 1):

It seems relate to Magemojo configuration. I got the same issue as your issue and I am contacting to magemojo to support. I have two site one use Stratus and it is getting this issue other site is fine without use Status and same source code.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/md3r9q  https://prnt.sc/md3rf6  https://prnt.sc/md3rlr could u please advise? how to solve?

Comment: let me know when u contacted  whether magemojo team provided support to fix this issue?

Comment: i found that public_html/update/vendor folder is missed in magento2 can u suggest how to fix?

Comment: the issue solved due to missing 'update' folder while deployed code in server.

Answer (score 0):

As explained here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_cron.html

This error you're facing is related to the Magento Update/Upgrade scripts. At the end of that Magento article they explain what to do when you get this error:

> In Composer-based installations, Magento creates the update/ directory when you run composer create-project. Running composer install does not create the update/ directory (if it did not exist before). See Recreate the Magento updater.

In any case, if you do not plan to upgrade your magento this way, you should consider removing the cron line automatically added by magento (the line should look like this):

> php /var/www/yourwebsite.com/update/cron.php >> /var/www/yourwebsite.com/var/log/update.cron.log